# CSS - How to make google maps size as big as the surrounding div?

Tags: css, google-maps, css-position

I have a google map and a design (iphone) and I want to display the map insight the 'phone'. When you click on the bottom button, the phone gets bigger and so should the google maps grow according to the current size of the phone.

The width works fine but not the height for some reason. If I user px or % for height, nothing is being displayed at all and how it is now, it doesnt work also.
Does anyone know why? I can include a jsfiddle if thats better" Thank you.

html:

```
<article id="devices">
    <div id="device" class="iphone">
        <div id="devicetop" class="iphone-speaker">
        </div>
        <div id="screen" class="iphone-screen">        
                    <div id="map-canvas"></div>

            </div>
            <a href="#">
                <div id="button" onclick="ipadSwitch()">
                     <div id="button-square">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
</article>
```

css:

```
  #map-canvas {
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;

 }
#screen {
  background-color: #c5c3ba;
  margin: 0 auto 0;
  border: 0.189em solid #aba99f;
  border-radius: 0.189em;
  width:10.08em;
  height:17.892em;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, your question should contain a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example, [here's how](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You must provide width and height for the parent div to be able to set the width/height to 100% on the child div, in this case #map-canvas

Comment: That is true for the height but not width when using non-floated, non-positioned (absolute/fixed) block level elements. Block level elements by default take up 100% width of their containing element.

Comment: Thanks, the more you know :D

Comment: The hight is fine now, (see update) but the problem now is that I cant move the content (the google maps) anymore, it became static.

Comment: use margin/padding or position relative with top/left/bottom/right ;)

Comment: so somehow its working now/I can move google maps around insight the screen, but the -/+ buttons disappeared from google maps..